# Turning a PPT into a .swf or any video format and keeping the animations

Tags: animation, flash, powerpoint

I've seen people use iSpring free to convert powerpoints to a swf file, but it seems to require Microsoft Office. Is there any alternative? I've already looked into OpenOffice, and it does conversion to .swf, but it doesn't save the animations and frame transitions, just a static image of each slide.

Answer (score 1):

I know only 2 types of solutions — using MS Office or OpenOffice, but OO really doesn't support animations and transitions. So software based on MS Office is better than OO-based.
However I never heard about ppt-to-flash conversion tools that can convert ppt files without PowerPoint

Comment: Is there a way to us MS Office without writing a clumsy macro/bot?